# Porque o OFF SET deixa o SQL mais lento?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Tenho o seguinte SQL, gerado pelo Entity Framework 6.

```sql
SELECT 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Project1].[CAMPO1] AS [CAMPO1], 
    [Project1].[CAMPO2] AS [CAMPO2], 
    [Project1].[CAMPO3] AS [CAMPO3], 
    [Project1].[CAMPO4] AS [CAMPO4], 
    [Project1].[CAMPO5] AS [CAMPO5], 
    [Project1].[CAMPO6] AS [CAMPO6], 
    [Project1].[TOTALCLICKS] AS [TOTALCLICKS]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent1].[CAMPO1] AS [CAMPO1], 
        [Extent1].[CAMPO2] AS [CAMPO2], 
        [Extent1].[CAMPO3] AS [CAMPO3], 
        [Extent1].[CAMPO4] AS [CAMPO4], 
        [Extent1].[CAMPO5] AS [CAMPO5], 
        [Extent1].[CAMPO6] AS [CAMPO6], 
        [Extent1].[TOTALCLICKS] AS [TOTALCLICKS], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [VIDEO] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [VIDEO_CATEGORIA] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[ID_VIDEO]
        WHERE [Extent2].[ID_CATEGORIA] = 25
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[TOTALCLICKS] DESC
    OFFSET 273910 ROWS FETCH NEXT 130 ROWS ONLY
```

Basicamente é um relacionamento entre a tabela de videos e video_categoria.

O plano de acesso informa que ele usa o index em video_categoria por id_video. O que é bom.

Depois ele vai para tabela de video e usa a chave primair id. Aqui ele gasta 98% do tempo.

Depois ele faz o loop e usa o índice de vídeo de total_clicks para ordenar e pegar os 130 do OFF SET.

Essa consulta leva mais de três minutos, o que não entendo é que se eu colocar o OFF SET começando do 1 ele executa em dois segundos (`OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 130 ROWS ONLY` )

Por que essa diferença?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É normal diminuir a performance, tendo que a pequisa precisa contar o primeiro offset + limite. Quanto maior o valor, mais a pesquisa demorará.

A pesquisa não vai direto ao OFFSET porque, primeiro, o registro pode ser diferente em tamanho, e segundo, não pode haver lacunas de registros excluídos. Ele precisa checar e contar cada registro novamente.

Esse código em `mysql` pode te ajudar, sendo id a chave primária, você pode usar isso para aumentar a velocidade:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    tabelaX
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT 10000, 30
        ) q
JOIN    tabelaX t
ON      t.id = q.id
```

leia mais em (inglês):

[MySQL ORDER BY / LIMIT performance: late row lookups](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/)